# Django 2 oauth2 toolkit register an application programmatically

Tags: superuser

Create a oauth2 application and get client_id and client_secret programmatically. This is helpful helpful for unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

For this at first needs to create super user.

```
class DefaultService(object):
    def create_super_user(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username='admin',
            email='admin@domain.com',
            password='admin',
            is_staff=True
        )

        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save()

        return user

    def create_oath2_application(self, user_id):
        application = Application(
            name="DjangoTest",
            client_id="PlaceYourClinetID",
            client_secret="PlaceYourClinetSecret",
            client_type="confidential",
            authorization_grant_type="password",
            user_id=user_id
        )

        application.save()

        return application
```